# Se pueden generar palabras aleatorias en una lista en python?

Tags: python, lista

La cuestión es que tengo un ejercicio como parte de un proyecto donde al niño le doy la siguiente lista:

```
   lista_palabras = ['Casa','Mesa','Silla','Computadora','Celular','Reloj','Collar','Planta','Arbol','Arbusto','Oso','Leon','Delfin','Tigre',
    'Elefante','Loro','Gato','Conejo']
```

y el niño debe adivinar de esa lista solo los elementos que correspondan a animales.
Mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera de que el programa genere palabras aleatorias dentro de la lista para que vayan cambiando y no sean siempre las mismas:

```
'Casa','Mesa','Silla','Computadora','Celular','Reloj','Collar','Planta','Arbol','Arbusto'
```

Los animales si creo que debería crear un par de listas mas con distintos animales ya que esas son las respuestas.
Esa es mi duda, se puede hacer eso o ya es programación un poco mas avanzada?

Comment: La respuesta es si.

Comment: Si, claro que se puede.

Comment: como puedo buscar en youtube tutoriales para realizar eso por favor, estuve buscando pero no encontre

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como te comentan, claro que esto se puede llevar a cabo, una opción es tener dos listas una con objetos y otra con animales, y llenar una nueva lista para jugar haciendo uso de las anteriores. Para hacer esto más aleatorio hacemos uso del modulo `random` más precisamente de sus utilidades `choice`y `randint`, creando un código como el siguiente:

```py
from random import choice, randint


animales = [
    "Gorila", "Chimpancé", "Caballo", "Ballena", "Perro", "Gato", "León", "Tigre", "Elefante",
    "Jirafa", "Delfín", "Camello", "León marino", "Hipopótamo", "Oso polar", "Ornitorrinco", 
    "Zorro", "Rinoceronte", "Guepardo", "Ratón", "Hiena", "Topo", "Jaguar"
    ]

cosas = [
    "armario","balcón", "baño", "comedor", "habitación", "despacho", "dormitorio", "espejo", 
    "fregadero", "horno", "horno microondas", "jardín", "lavabo", "lavadero", "lavaplatos", 
    "pasillo", "patioi", "salón", "sótano", "techo", "bañera", "cama", "cocina", "cocina" ,
    "escalera" ,"lavadora" , "mesa" , "nevera", "puerta", "silla", "terraza", "ventana"
     ]

# Cambiar por la cantidad que gustes tal que no supere a su arreglo correspondiente
cantidad_animales = 5 
cantidad_cosas = 5
juego= []
cantidad_a_elegir = cantidad_cosas + cantidad_animales 

while len(juego) != cantidad_a_elegir:
    # Agregamos algo mas de aleatoriedad al armado de la lista y algo de uniformidad en su contenido
    if (randint(0, 100) % 2 == 0 and cantidad_animales != 0):
        animal_elegido = choice(animales)
        # No queremos animales repetidos
        if animal_elegido not in juego:
            juego.append(animal_elegido)
            cantidad_animales-=1
    elif (cantidad_cosas != 0): 
        cosa_elegida = choice(cosas)
        #No queremos cosas repetidas
        if cosa_elegida not in juego:
            juego.append(cosa_elegida)
            cantidad_cosas-=1

print(juego)
```

Puedes agregar más elementos a tus listas de [animales](https://www.somosmamas.com.ar/para-chicos/nombres-de-animales/#Nombres_de_animales_para_aprender_jugar_y_divertirse) y de [cosas](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ndice:1000_palabras_b%C3%A1sicas_en_espa%C3%B1ol). Espero que te sirva, saludos :)

Comment: te agradezo mucho amigo, me ha servido un montón :,)

Comment: Me alegro mucho, se que hay funcionalidades de la librería que implementan esto y que con una línea resuelven el problema, pero siempre está bueno "complicarse" para aprender en estos casos

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que quieres mezclar las dos listas de modo de tener una "cosa" por cada `nro` animales. Por ejemplo, para tener un 80% de animales y un 20% de cosas, colocamos `nro = 4` (una cosas por cuatro animales).

La lista debe salir desordenada, para que el niño no detecte ningún patrón.

```
import random

animales = [
    "Gorila", "Chimpancé", "Caballo", "Ballena", "Perro", "Gato", "León", "Tigre", "Elefante",
    "Jirafa", "Delfín", "Camello", "León marino", "Hipopótamo", "Oso polar", "Ornitorrinco",
    "Zorro", "Rinoceronte", "Guepardo", "Ratón", "Hiena", "Topo", "Jaguar"
    ]

cosas = [
    "armario","balcón", "baño", "comedor", "habitación", "despacho", "dormitorio", "espejo",
    "fregadero", "horno", "horno microondas", "jardín", "lavabo", "lavadero", "lavaplatos",
    "pasillo", "patioi", "salón", "sótano", "techo", "bañera", "cama", "cocina", "cocina" ,
    "escalera" ,"lavadora" , "mesa" , "nevera", "puerta", "silla", "terraza", "ventana"
     ]

nro = 4   # Cada cuantos animales por cosa.
total = animales + random.sample(cosas, len(animales) // nro)
random.shuffle(total)
print(total)
```

produce:

> ['Perro', 'Gorila', 'horno', 'Guepardo', 'Tigre', 'Zorro', 'Ratón', 'Jaguar', 'Camello', 'Oso polar', 'Caballo', 'Topo',
> 'Hipopótamo', 'Delfín', 'Chimpancé', 'techo', 'León marino',
> 'Elefante', 'Gato', 'Hiena', 'Ornitorrinco', 'Ballena', 'balcón',
> 'León', 'pasillo', 'Rinoceronte', 'espejo', 'Jirafa']
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

La librería estándar `random` nos provee métodos convenientes, como `sample(población, k)`, que te retorna una lista de `k` elementos seleccionados de la secuencia/set `población` (sin repetición).

En este caso sacamos de la lista de "cosas" la cantidad justa para distribuir entre los "animales". Esa cantidad es

```
len(animales) // nro
```

El resultado es una lista con los animales seguidos de una selección de cosas. Usamos el método `shuffle(población)` para *desordenar* la secuencia. La operación modifica la secuencia `población`.

Eso es todo. Python es maravilloso porque no necesitas iterar como en lenguajes primitivos.

Comment: Buenísima implementación inspirada de mi misma idea, shuffle es la opción simple, más conocida y óptima en estos casos, no es necesario ensuciarse las manos desarrollando "a la vieja escuela", igual al final del dia a bajo nivel sucede lo mismo, el uso de utilidades ofuscadas no significa que ciertas cosas no se estén aconteciendo :)

Comment: @LichiMartinez. Humm, perdón? No alcanzo a ver la inspiración que mencionas.

Comment: Dejando de lado el hecho de que es la misma idea, implementada de formas diferentes. Dado que tú respuesta salió horas después que la mía siendo que habías comentado la publicación mucho antes de que yo respondiese y no te molestaste en responder, y en detalles como la estructura dinámica y estática de tu código, nombres de variables, los comentarios como (sin repetición) y el detalle de que python de la posibilidad de no iterar (que aprovecho te faltó el detalle, de que esto solo es a nivel sintaxis), me hacen sospechar que te inspírate. Y no hay nada de malo en eso, ni hay porque ofenderse

Comment: Está excelente tu implementación, altamente legible y eficiente, es más la prefiero sobre la mía, se nota que sos impecable desarrollando solo que me parece muy ofuscada para una persona que está pidiendo un tutorial en Youtube para manejar listas.